# Decisions using Template Tags

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have a templated class which I need to instantiate depending on command line arguments.

There must be a better way than what I can think of:

```
if (optionA == 1){
    if (optionB == 2){
        myclass <Option1, Option2, Option3> object;
    }
}
else if (optionA == 2){
 // a whole big if-else ladder
}
```

This doesn't even allow me to use my templated object outside the scope of the if statement! By the way, all the options are tags

Comment: What is a template tag?

Comment: `if (optionB = 2)` should be `if (optionB == 2)`

Comment: probably not the best definition, but class objects which define the behaviour of the class which they template. Iterators in the STL have this. http://www.generic-programming.org/languages/cpp/techniques.php

Comment: I had the same question - I would call that a policy (Alexandrescu) or traits (std lib) class.

Comment: @ScottJones My program makes use of traits and policy style programming, but I don't think you use that to instantiate the object of the class though

Comment: Well, you would use them to parameterize a template, as you're doing with your options.  "Tag" is usuallly associated with a technique for dispatching to an overloaded set of methods, using type information only (supplied by a temp object ignored by the method).

Answer (score 1):

Your challenge is that you want a compile-time decision (option type selection) to be based on runtime data (args).  I could imagine a macro/template solution that generated a 'parse tree', mapping option codes to tags.  But this would result in a combinatorial explosion to generate the templated types, which would slow compilation (and probably runtime).  An alternative would be to use factory methods for each option, passing option objects to your myclass constructor.  Not as efficient as pure compile-time generation, but I don't see an alternative.